# Memory leak in Python-C++ interface?

Tags: c++, python, memory-leaks

I have a piece of C++ code with python-C++ interface that need to be called repeatedly with a python list as its input. I found even the dummy process as following leads to memory leak:

In python:

```
a = [1.0]*1000
for c in range(1000):
    dummy(a, 1)
```

In C++:

```
static PyObject* dummy(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Am I miss anything here so it introduces memory leak?

Comment: I don't think so... Are you sure it's a memory leak and not just the GC not running yet?

Comment: Actually, I tried to add periodically manual GC to the code, but the memory still blows up quickly.

Comment: I don't see the [tag:swig] link here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No that's fine, objects you get passed to your c method are only borrowed, i.e. you don't have to decrease the refcount of the objects before returning (as a matter of fact that would be a bad, bad bug).

See for example this part of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/arg.html):

> Note that any Python object references which are provided to the
>   caller are borrowed references; do not decrement their reference
>   count!

How are you even determining that you have a memory leak? It's more than likely that that's your problem.